# Find the peak of real part of inverse Fourier transform of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

How do I get the argmax of an image in term of coordinates(dxk, dyk) as described in the equation below.

[image]

Where ck is the inverse fourier transform of an image(upsampled by k).

I'm stuck after this line of code

```
[argvalue, argmax] = max(real(ck));
%should be something like this:
%[dxk, dyk]=max(real(ck));
```

Thanks.

Comment: argmax is a mathematical term that **does not** mean maximum. `argmax_x { F(x) }` means "find the `x` that makes `F(x)` maximum", thus the result of the argmax function is an specific `x`, not the `max(F(x))`

Comment: what do you get in variable argmax?

Comment: I get a column of matrix [1 720 1 1 720 1 1 720 1 1 720 1...]
i guess that's their indices. Whereas argvalue consist sets of value

Comment: argvalue= [0.111111111111111 0.0759912192816660 0.0459434185838530 0 0.0189976013640047 0.0183759897362286 0 0.0108549583546861 0.0114833944036848...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is this:

```
[m,w] = max(real(ck));
[~,y] = max(m);
x = w(y);
```

Another one is this:

```
[~,w] = max(real(ck(:)));
[x,y] = ind2sub(size(ck),w);
```